# Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-meta/lib/meta at missingModule (vendor.js:18453)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using

```
ember-cli: 3.4.3 ,
node js:10.16.3.
```

ember-serve work perfectly and give

```
Build successful (25929ms) – Serving on http://localhost:4232/
```

but on browser console the following error comes and unable to process further

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-meta/lib/meta at missingModule (vendor.js:18453)
```

while using sourceMap found that the line which cause the issue is this

```
const Meta = false ? Ember.__loader.require('@ember/-internals/meta/lib/meta').Meta : Ember.__loader.require('ember-meta/lib/meta').Meta;
```

I tried deleting package-lock.json ,node-modules, clearing cache & reinstalling still the same

Can any one help on this please

Comment: Are you able to try out a newer version of Ember?

Comment: Found the issue with one dependency in package.json "ember-light-table": "2.0.0-beta.4" It seems this version of ember table is not compatible with other ember dependencies reverted it to "ember-light-table": "2.0.0-beta.3", now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

**Addon version must be compatible with ember version**

It is to be noted that this issue occurred for me after installing an ember addon.

So what worked for me was uninstalling the old addon and re-installing the  compatible version of the addon.

Uninstall old ember addon

```
npm uninstall [insert addon-name here] --save-dev
```

Install specific version of ember addon

```
npm install [insert addon-name here]@[insert compatible-version here]--save-dev
```

Generate addon

```
ember g [insert addon-name here]
```